# selenium chrome not open the url inside loop

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
options = [Options(), Options()]
options[0].add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options[0].add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\balckbeard\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options[0].add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 1')
driver = [
    webdriver.Chrome(options=options[0])
]
driver[0].get('https://stackoverflow.com/')    
options[1].add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options[1].add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\balckbeard\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options[1].add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 2')
driver = [
    webdriver.Chrome(options=options[1])
]
driver[1].get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

im just a bit confuse why my profile 2 wont load the url. So in first loop it will open Profile 1 and success open the url, then in second Profile 2 will open but the url not open.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
driver = driver + [webdriver.Chrome(options=options[1])]
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
options = [Options(), Options()]
options[0].add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options[0].add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\balckbeard\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options[0].add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 1')
driver = [
    webdriver.Chrome(options=options[0])
]
driver[0].get('https://stackoverflow.com/')    
options[1].add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options[1].add_argument('user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\balckbeard\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data')
options[1].add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 2')
driver = driver + [
    webdriver.Chrome(options=options[1])
]
driver[1].get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

what I use is edge

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
# from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver import EdgeOptions as Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
import time
options = [Options(), Options()]
options[0].add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options[0].add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 1')
service=Service(executable_path = r'C:\Users\10696\Desktop\access\zhihu\msedgedriver\msedgedriver.exe')
driver = [
    webdriver.Edge(options=options[0], service = service)
]
driver[0].get('https://stackoverflow.com/')    
options[1].add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options[1].add_argument('profile-directory=Profile 2')
driver = driver + [
    webdriver.Chrome(options=options[1])
]
driver[1].get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work or stay the same

Comment: In my experiment, it works fine.

Comment: well yeah, but I need to use it with chrome :)